# Create a fully onboarded stripe connect account for testing purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'd like to be able to quickly run code in automated tests and development [to create a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#accept-payment):

```rb
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_51HYHSFGtUKse83O9J4QeAib3cp8sHzGaOQRrnwvnghEzuYQKUCKEP3CHE3AIHe5ModevMK7TVAUCyJU0ADSwIUoX00qxZmBI9r'

session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [{
    name: 'Kavholm rental',
    amount: 1000,
    currency: 'aud',
    quantity: 1,
  }],
  payment_intent_data: {
    application_fee_amount: 123,
    transfer_data: {
      destination: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
    },
  },
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/failure',
})
```

but note that it needs a `CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID`

The problem here is you have to manually go through the browser to create it. Very annoying for automated testing and development if you're constantly seeding new data.

How can I create a connected stripe account using code (rather than going through the browser)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the type of Connect Account you're using, but the only flavor that would allow that is [a Custom Account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts). If you're using Standard or Express, it makes more sense to specifically create - and reuse - test accounts for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it's an express account. It just seems like an anti-pattern to not have reproducible code in the seeds file. Like, if I want to do this for a new app, I have to manually go and create things through the browser (remembering all the instructions along the way). Or write some selenium code to do it for me. Seems like an errant omission from the Stripe API that it seems not to be able to do this, or at least, it's not documented how to do this. In any case, I'll use your recommendation of doing manual setup and reusing those accounts.

Comment: do you know what email addresses to use in test accounts? Unlike phone number, stripe doesn't provide a default. Also, I don't want to accidentally spam real people